# Handling connection pool exhaustion and avoiding deadlock in Hibernate/C3P0

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, dining-philosopher

My old application following chain to query my database: `Spring Tx -> Hibernate -> C3P0`. Now I need to implement new features based on the existing architecture.

I normally enter a transactional context by using either the `@Transactional` annotation or manually invoking the `PlatformTransactionManager`.

Sometimes, to perform asynchronous and big data operations, I open a stateless session using the `SessionFactory` API. We never had any additional problem as our thread pool is well controlled

For the first time, my requirement is to perform several DB operations in parallel to speed up performance. I have a doubt about it, because I am extremely careful about multithreaded operations.

For each entity in the database, I can perform a reconciliation operation on a separate thread. But each reconciliation operation uses a pair of connections for each of the two threads it spawns. So there are basically 4 connections for each thread.

Multithreading class teaches students that in order to prevent a deadlock (eating philosophers issue), resources shall be acquired in a transactional way: once you have acquired a fork, if you cannot acquire the second in a reasonable time, release the first and try again.

My question is simple. Given the `SessionFactory` API, how can I write code that won't wait indefinitely for 4 connections from c3p0 if the pool is full? I mean I need 4 `StatelessSession`s only if there is room for 4, otherwise I can wait and retry.

As far as I know, the `SessionFactory` API is blocking and does not allow to set a watchdog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the idea is to use the plain old workaround.

In general, in Java world, if an API does not offer a watchdog method for acquiring a resource, you can delegate that to a `Future`, which offers `get(int timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit)` API to constrain the execution.

### Step 1: watchdog timer for resource acquire

So basically, how do I get a stateless session within the bounds of a timeout?

```
private Future<StatelessSession> getStatelessSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    return asyncTaskExecutor.submit(new Callable<StatelessSession>()
    {

        @Override
        public StatelessSession call() throws Exception
        {
            return sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
        }
    });
}

try {
    StatelessSession session = getStatelessSession(sessionFactory).get(3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // go to step 2
}
```

### Step 2: eat the way a philosopher would do

As I said, my problem looks basically like the dining philosopher, except that we don't just have two forks but spoons and knives to take for a total of 4.

```
StatelessSession session1, session2, session3, session4;
for (int i=0; i<MAX_ATTEMPTS;i++) {
    try {
        session1 = tryGetSessionOrBoooooom();
    } catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        continue;
    }
    try {
        session2 = tryGetSessionOrBoooooom();
    } catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        session1.close();
        continue;
    }
    try {
        session3 = tryGetSessionOrBoooooom();
    } catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        session2.close();
        session1.close();
        continue;
    }
    try {
        session4 = tryGetSessionOrBoooooom();
    } catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        session3.close();
        session2.close();
        session1.close();
        continue;
    }
}
```

What happens if you go beyond `MAX_ATTEMPTS` is up to you, developer!